# Mandarin Equivalent: 屙尿都屙不伸?

Tags: translation, mandarin, topolect

As the title says, what's the Mandarin equivalent of the phrase `屙尿都屙不伸`?

The phrase describes someone who *can't do anything*, and is pretty much useless.

An English equivalent might be something like `couldn't organise a piss up in a brewery` - and such phrases like that.

Comment: Never heard of this phase...could it be 屙尿都屙不`長`?

Comment: Na, it's definitely 伸 : as in `cant even pee straight`

Comment: straight should be "直", and "伸直" is a term, maybe 直? Because I haven't heard of the term seriously.  Is it in Cantonese when you heard / read about it?

Comment: Well the original phrase doesn't matter *that* much! I'm just looking for similar terms in Mandarin

Comment: @user3306356 Well sometimes it helps when we know better about its context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

吃啥啥不剩; 干啥啥不行.

Whatever (he) eats, (he) leaves over nothing; whatever (he) builds, (he) bungles everything. Used mostly on bureaucrats. When a hierarchical organization grows tall enough, it selects almost exclusively characters like this.